Prevent `ssh-keygen -R` from creating a backup file
I have an automated process that regularly SSHes to about 120 different machines over a VPN. Occasionally these machines switch IP addresses and use addresses that were previously used by different machines. This causes problems with host key checking when logging in via SSH.
To circumvent this, the process runs ssh-keygen -R to remove the host key from known_hosts prior to accessing each machine via SSH.
Unfortunately, each time this command runs, it seems to create a backup file of known_hosts named known_hosts.ABCDEFGH where "ABCDEFGH" is a random sequence of letters.
Recently I discovered approximately 750,000 of these backup files, taking up 34GB of hard drive space, on the server that runs the automated process.
Short of removing known_hosts.* each time I run ssh-keygen, is there a way to prevent this build-up of files? I.e. is there a way to prevent ssh-keygen from backing up the known_hosts file when it modifies it?
I've noticed this behavior on both Ubuntu 22.04 and on MacOS 13.6.6.

That's not a backup; that's a temporary new file. -H or -R writes to known_hosts.(random_new) and when done renames that to known_hosts after renaming known_hosts to known_hosts.old (replacing any older one). Your -R operations apparently have been frequently failing or getting killed before completing. However, if you use only names to connect and need to reuse addresses, you can just (1) configure CheckHostIP no on old versions of OpenSSH or (2) use 8.5 up which does this by default (and Ubuntu  22.04 should have 8.9!)

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks. That's good info. I did a little digging and it looks like a large number of threads are running ssh-keygen concurrently. I've synchronized them and will watch to see if it resolves the issue. If it doesn't resolve the issue then maybe I've misidentified the source and it's the ssh process itself creating the files when it adds keys, and still possibly something to do with concurrency.

Serializing my ssh-keygen -R runs seems to have solved, or at least significantly reduced the issue. Will keep an eye on it. Alternate workaround is to not use a known_hosts file at all (UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null).

As pointed out in a comment, these were actually temporary files that, for some reason, ssh-keygen was failing to delete (despite the operation itself succeeding).
As it turns out, my automated process was running ssh-keygen concurrently on multiple threads at the same time (sometimes 50-100 instances starting simultaneously). I guess this was making ssh-keygen choke a bit when manipulating the known_hosts file.
Synchronizing the threads and serializing all of the ssh-keygen runs solved the issue entirely.
It does highlight a risk of running ssh-keygen simultaneously from multiple threads / processes, and I wonder if it's a bug in ssh-keygen, but for now my fix seems to be working. In any case I've filed an ssh-keygen bug report here just in case.
An alternative "fix" is to not use a known_hosts file at all by setting the UserKnownHostsFile option to /dev/null, which bypasses the problem entirely.
